# Tengo estos errores cuando corro npm install, ya he intentado todo, alguien sabe como se soluciona?

Tags: npm

```
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/emiramir1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/node.h:63:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/emiramir1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8.h:30:
npm ERR! /Users/emiramir1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:697:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
npm ERR! template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
npm ERR!                                                  ^
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/emiramir1/MSL/mslgroup.com/docroot/themes/custom/msl_base/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/emiramir1/MSL/mslgroup.com/docroot/themes/custom/msl_base/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/emiramir1/MSL/mslgroup.com/docroot/themes/custom/msl_base/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/emiramir1/.npm/_logs/2022-10-03T16_26_04_926Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Poner sólo una traza de error no es una pregunta válida en el sitio. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Esa versión de node-sass que intentas usar (no sabemos cual porque no hay package.json en tu pregunta) no es compatible con node16. Sólo a partir de node-sass 6.0.1 existe esa compatibilidad, creo.

Entonces, o subes node-sass o bajas node a v14 (sugiero siempre usar nvm para no pelear con el entorno de desarrollo).